# Spring boot application without Tomcat: how to "daemonize"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I removed REST part from my basic Spring Boot application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.class,
    WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class}) // Do not start Tomcat yet
@ComponentScan
public class ViewsAggregatorApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IllegalAccessException {
    SpringApplication.run( MyApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

I have found out that my application quits immediately. I however intent to have inside AMQP listener and sender, so I'd like it to stay running. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: If you have a listener in there is should keep running as that starts some threads to listen to queues. If you don't want tomcat then don't include the web related parts instead of excluding the auto configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum Listener I have yet to make. But in fact I might want just have sender and timer inside.

Comment: Then create the sender that will also start a thread that should keep things alive.